# Trying to open up Word Addin using VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, cpu-word, word-addins

Im using VSTO to develop the word addin. I have already developed the ribbon but I cant figure out a way to get the sidebar to open. I have attached a example image of what is required. Basically just like what Grammaly has done, On button press the sidebar to open.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD0tT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Walkthrough: Synchronize a custom task pane with a Ribbon button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-synchronizing-a-custom-task-pane-with-a-ribbon-button?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) demonstrates how to create a custom task pane that users can hide or display by clicking a toggle button on the ribbon.

The [How to: Add a custom task pane to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) guide explains how to create a task pane in any Office application. For example, declare your user control which will be used for the custom task pane and the task pane instance in the following way:

```
private TaskPaneControl taskPaneControl1;
private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane taskPaneValue;
```

Then create a new instance add the following code to the `ThisAddIn_Startup` or any ribbon event handler. This code creates a new `CustomTaskPane` by adding the `MyUserControl` object to the `CustomTaskPanes` collection. The code also displays the task pane.:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    taskPaneControl1 = new TaskPaneControl();
    taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(
        taskPaneControl1, "MyCustomTaskPane");
    taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged +=
        new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
}

private void taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.Ribbons.ManageTaskPaneRibbon.toggleButton1.Checked = 
        taskPaneValue.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom Task Pane. Start at the documentation links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp